# what is the best practice of handling time in R?

Tags: r, datetime

I am working with a survey dataset. It has two string `vectors`, `start` and `finish`, indicating the time of the day when the interview was started, and finished, respectively.

They are `character` strings that look like: `"9:24 am"`, `"12:35 pm"`, and so forth. I am trying to calculate the duration of the interview based on these two. What is the best way of doing this?

I know that, for dates, there are lots of `classe`s or `function`s like `as.date()`, `as.Date()`, `chron()`, or `as.POSIXct()`. So I was looking for something like `as.time()`, but could not find it. Should I just append a made-up date and convert the whole thing into a `POSIX()` date-time `class`, then use `difftime()`?

What is the best practice of handling time in `R`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use `strptime()` to convert the string to a date. For example:

```
strptime("9:24 am",format="%I:%M %p")
```

Then you can take differences just by taking one away from the other:

```
strptime("9:24 am",format="%I:%M %p")-strptime("12:14 am",format="%I:%M %p")
Time difference of 9.166667 hours
```

You can store this and then do an `as.numeric()` if you just want the number out, otherwise you can pass around the time objects.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

one option is to use regular expressions. if you are not familiar with them, they are used to parse strings using patterns. i would research regular expressions and then [here are the functions in r](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html)

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

best practice is using lubridate package

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.5.6/topics/hm

```
hm(c("09:10", "09:02", "1:10"))
## [1] "9H 10M 0S" "9H 2M 0S"  "1H 10M 0S
```

Then use difftime for difference in the date time formats created above
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/difftime.html

```
difftime(time1, time2, tz,
         units = c("auto", "secs", "mins", "hours",
                   "days", "weeks"))
```